# Is candlestick chart real time update possible with QCandlestickSeries in pyqt

Tags: qt, pyqt, candlestick-chart, qtcharts

I am trying create a python widget to plot candlestick chart with real time data in trading hours. So looking for best option to do it. I found QCandlestickSeries but it is not clear if we can get the chart to update with good performance when we keep updating last candle and when we keep adding new candle every x interval. Has someone tried this? Anyone knows if this is possible?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "realtime"? How often do you expect it to update it?

Comment: @musicamante I want to update chart once every second with the LTP of the symbol

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what LTP is or how the data is updated. If it requires a network request, consider using a QThread or the QtNetwork interface. If the update doesn't require possibly blocking functions, just use a QTimer.

Comment: LTP is Last Traded Price of anything that is traded in share market. I am not concerned about how to get the data from network. I am able to get the data. I want to know if using QCandlestickSeries I can update the chart with this data. How do i set this new data on the chart?

Comment: You should be concerned if retrieving the data is a potentially blocking function, as it would make the *whole* UI freeze in the meantime. Besides, setting the data once or updating at intervals doesn't change anything, it's just a matter of calling the update function whenever you need it. So, it's not really clear what you're asking: is your question "how can I call my update function every second"? In that case, as said, look into QTimer. But if you're asking "how can I update the graph with the data", then we cannot answer you as your question is too broad, as SO is not a tutorial website.

Comment: No, my question is how to update only the last candle because that will be the only data that will change. I am looking for efficient way to do that. If I set all the data again or update with all new data, it will be slow because I want to have multiple charts in a single window and update them every x interval. So is there a way to update only the last candle and add a new candle with rest of chart data not changing?
I have used QTimer to fetch data every x interval and it is working.

Comment: I suggest you to [edit] your question in order to improve it, clarify what you're already achieved and what you are not, and possibly provide a [mre] that shows what you've got so far.

Comment: Look at the `QCandlestickSeries` member functions [`append`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcandlestickseries.html#append), [`sets`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcandlestickseries.html#sets) and [`take`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcandlestickseries.html#take).  Between them they should provide basic series manipulation.